# Jquery function no result if imported to soon?

Tags: jquery

I created a simple function with Jquery and it works, but if I import it to soon it doesn't work, for example

```
<html land="en">
<head>
    <meta carset="utf-8">
    <title> Jquery 2 </title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inline is JS in the HTML file -->
<p id="paragraph"> This is a paragraph </p>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Tutorial2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works, but if I did this

```
<html land="en">
<head>
    <meta carset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Tutorial2.js"></script>
    <title> Jquery 2 </title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inline is JS in the HTML file -->
<p id="paragraph"> This is a paragraph </p>

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work.

Is it because my function in Tutorial2.js uses a reference to p id="paragraph" and as the Javascript file is loaded before the page, the function doesn't know what I am telling it to access. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the reason : when you bind an event handler to an element, this element must exist.

The usual solution is to use the [$.ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which executes the callback you pass only after the DOM is ready :

```
$(function(){
   // your code using the DOM
});
```

Then you may have your code in the HEAD.

Another solution, but more costly, would be to use delegation when binding :

```
$(document.body).on('event', 'yourselector'), function(){
      //
});
```

Comment: Could I just ask, what do you mean by DOM?

Comment: The DOM is the document object model : all the objects the browser creates as a reification of your document.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready
```

this is what you need.